# Dreamweaver Auto completing apostrophes

Tags: autocomplete, dreamweaver, apostrophe

The new Dreamweaver 5.5 closes the apostrophe as soon as you open it.  Is there anyway to turn this feature off?  I thought it would be with the auto html closing tags, but its not.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dreamweaver 5.5:

1. Open the Preferences panel.
2. From the left Category column, select Code Hints
3. Either uncheck Enable code hints or set the delay to a longer period of time.

This will either completely stop the autocomplete (and code hints) or cause it to wait for a period of time before attempting to autocomplete them.